# How to delete all files by a specific name? CryptoWall trojan

Tags: windows, delete-file, trojan

How can I delete all file that by this name: HELP_DECRYPT.url
On internet there is a way but it doesn't work. That solution is this: in `cmd del /s HELP_DECRYPT.url`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find the solution: 
in cmd

```
del /s \aaaaa.*
```

aaaa is the name
* for any extension